# How to read a key from c# symmetric encryption objects as string

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement an encryption helper class that uses the in built GenerateKey methods to generate a random key and return it as a string. The objects I am using are;

- DESCryptoServiceProvider
- RC2CryptoServiceProvider
- RijndaelManaged

After calling the GenenrateKey method for the selected object, I then try to convert the key to a string to be returned.

My problem is none of the functions i've seen used on this and various other sites seem to be working the way I want. For example if I run the following example for a DES encryption object;

```
public String GenerateRandomKey()
{
  DESCryptoServiceProvider encryptObject = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
  encryptObject.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
  encryptObject.GenerateKey();

  string key = 
      Convert.ToBase64String(encryptObject.Key,0,encryptObject.Key.Length); 
  return key;
}
```

An example of the key string returned is A01190NXvPI=, which is 12 characters, but I was expecting a string of 8 characters for DES. The other encryption methods similarly return key strings that are too long.

I felt sure this was just an encoding problem, but I've tried them all, still with no luck. I've also tried adding logic to strip out any padding or return characters that might be present in the key byte array, but again no luck.

Comment: The `key` you see is 12 characters because it is the base64-encoded representation of the real key. What you should be looking at is `encryptObject.Key.Length`.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for replying so quickly. I'm a little confused though, isn't Key.length just the count of the number of bytes that make up the key? Stepping through the code, the count looks correct (8) in the case of DES, but I thought each byte then needed converting to a character so the returning string would be the same length?

Comment: Why did you think that? As with most things in crypto, the key is binary -- it does not make sense to print it because it does not represent anything printable. So if you do want to print it or something related you have to convert it to some other representation, at which point everything is dependent on how you convert.

Comment: I've posted an answer, but it's not actually clear what the question is here.  Maybe define "working the way I want", or use the phrase "How do I ... ?"

Comment: To clarify, the question seems to me to be about text encoding and is not about encryption at all.  See if you can get rid of the irrelevant half of this question (whichever half it is).

Comment: Hi bmm6o, thanks for your reply. What I was really trying to achieve was to generate an alphanumeric key so it would be readable to a human, so you are correct that this more a question about text encoding than encryption. I think to get the correct key length from the GenerateKey function I would have to use an encoding scheme that would give me undesirable characters so I think it's best if I change my approach altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (single) DES key is 56 bits, so it can be stored in 7 bytes.  There are several common ways to represent arbitrary binary data as a String, such as hex encoding and base64 encoding.  Any common encoding method will create a string with more characters in it than there were bytes in the original data, since each character carries less than 8 bits of information.  If this is undesirable, rethink what you are trying to accomplish by converting the byte array to a string.